# How can I write a method that returns an unique string of 6 characters length?

Tags: c#, random

If I do it like this I get some duplicates...

```
private const string _chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123654987";

public string RandomString(int size)
{
    var random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 3));

    var buffer = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = _chars[random.Next(_chars.Length)];
    }
    return new string(buffer);
}
```

The first 100000 request must be unique how can I guarantee it basically...
if possible I do not want to keep a list and query it...

Comment: you can't without caching it. that's the peculiar thing about randomness.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Don't you mean the... *puts on sunglasses*... random thing about randomness?

Comment: Do you want something unique or random? They are very different.

Comment: Does it need to involve randomness? Interlocked.Increment(ref last).ToSting("000000") would do the job...

Comment: I know this sounds slightly facetious but the numbers 1-100,000 are unique and can be made up to six characters long (000001) - you'd only need to remember what the last number you issued was.

Comment: I need unique strings... this is the first time I see Interlocked, I will look at it.

Answer (score 2):

- Figure out the largest prime that's less than 35^6 (the number of possible combinations).
- Choose a random number that's less than that but greater than one.
- Take (your prime % (your random number * iteration index)).  This is what you base your string from.
- Express the result in base 35, and create your string.

These strings won't overlap over 100,000 iterations because your random number is relatively prime to the larger number.  No caching needed.

You can run through a random number of iterations before recording the strings to give yourself a larger result space.

Comment: This sounds really nice, but it doesn't work.  Check the algorithm, but I think you're got an invalid assumption about what relative primality buys you.

Answer (score 0):

If your possible length of random string is limited it would be easiest to use GUIDs:

A crude implementation might be:

```
    public string RandomString(int size)
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid()
            .ToString()
            .Replace("-","")
            .Substring(0, size);
    }
```

If you need longer then you could concatenate multiple GUID strings together.

Comment: Good point - its the total string that's unique isn't it. Can you think of a way to capture that? Would it be sufficient to take the last n chars instead of the first n?

Comment: GUIDs are not unique. The range of possible values is just so large that it's very unlikely to get the same value twice when picking two values randomly.

Comment: The problem It needs to be 6 character long.

Comment: @SerdarBuyuktemiz even if the size of GUID is ok for you, they are not unique anyway.

Comment: @dtb. I know that, but for most practical purposes that's the same thing: There are 3.4*10^38 guids. So even when generating 100000 of them your chances of having two the same are vanishingly small. Of course this is all dependent on the algorith used to generate the GUIDs. I was wondering if it was possible to capture this to generate a smaller string randomly.

Comment: @JonEgerton: As soon as you make the range of possible values smaller, the chances become much higher. It doesn't matter if you calculate the values from values in a larger range of possible values.

Comment: @JonEgerton *chances of having two the same are vanishingly small.* but it is still there.

Comment: @dtb/tugberk. Consider the number of possible 6 char strings. (correct me if my maths is wrong here). There are only 36^6 possible alphanumeric 6 char strings. That's only 2176782336 possible values. Once you've used that many you're certain to repeat anyway. I'd just use a GUID and take my chances!

Comment: @dtb: GUIDs should be truly unique, since they incorporate a machine-unique portion (typically MAC address) and combine that with a locally unique part (based on timestamp and a counter).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Afaik that type of GUIDs isn't used very often for privacy reasons. V4 GUIDs are completely filled with pseudo-random bits.

Comment: @dtb: the MAC address may not appear in the GUID, but there's a portion which identifies the machine, and a portion which is locally unique.  That's why generation of a group of GUIDs generates a clearly recognizable sequence (these nibbles are constant, those count upwards, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep a list of all earlier values.  Just use a counter.

If you want to make the value less predictable (guessable) to a user, use a hash function to scramble the bits before using them.  But still generate the next input to the hash from a simple counter.

Comment: this sounds nice... I will look at Interlocked first... Then probable Hash the counter value...

Answer (score 0):

If you used an int to represent bit positions, you could do it easily.

```
int bits=0

...

while(bitCount(bits)!=6) // Write your own bitCount method--or there is probably one on the net
    bits++;
```

Now you know you have 6 bits in your int, so convert them to the string

For instance with your data:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123654987"
```

if you were counting and had reached 111111, (The first one you will hit) you'd return "234567", the next one I believe will be 1011111 which will return "134567" then "1101111" which will return "124567".  (I could be getting the sequence wrong, it's just off the top of my head).

It will always be unique, and the iterating isn't as expensive as you'd think, although you could probably be a bit smarter than just iterating (you could skip large groups if you figured out it was mathematically impossible to reach the next 6-"on" bit number before n increments, or you could just come up with a more straight-forward algorithm to generate the next integer with 6 1's.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use current time stamp (milliseconds, microseconds or nannoseconds) (reverse it or change the digit order if you need to show a randomness) and replace the digits in the timestamp number with A-Z and 0-9 characters on some criteria.

Otherwise If you don't have any caching mechanism store previously generated values, I think you cannot get random and UNIQUE character sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't need to be random but only unique then this code works using an odometer type of output.

```
public class Class1
{
    List<char> _chars = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
        'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2','3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
    private static int[] index = new int[6] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private const int charMax = 35;

    public string UniqueString()
    {
        if (index[5] > charMax)
        {
            IncromentParent(5);
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.Append(_chars[index[0]]);
        result.Append(_chars[index[1]]);
        result.Append(_chars[index[2]]);
        result.Append(_chars[index[3]]);
        result.Append(_chars[index[4]]);
        result.Append(_chars[index[5]]);

        index[5]++;
        return result.ToString();
    }

    private void IncromentParent(int active)
    {
        if (active == 0)
            throw new Exception("out of numbers");

        int parent = active - 1;
        index[active] = 0;
        index[parent]++;
        if (index[parent] > charMax)
            IncromentParent(parent);
    } 
}
```

And here is a passing unit test, but it takes a long time to run...

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    Class1 target = new Class1();
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {            
        string result = target.UniqueString();

        if (!results.Contains(result))
            results.Add(result);
        else
            Assert.Fail(string.Format("The string '{0}' is already in the list", result));
    }
   Console.WriteLine(results.Count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thank you very much... but I also need some randomness... strings must be uncertain... I guess I will use timespan and mix something with it.